normal topological space equivalent condition
Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$. A neighbourhood of $A$ is a subset $U\subseteq X$ such that there exists open subset $O$ with $A\subset O\subset U$. I want to prove: $X$ is normal, iff any closed subset has closed neighborhood.
"$\Rightarrow$" is obviously, I have problem with $\Leftarrow$. Let $A,B$ be two closed, disjoint subsets. By condition I can find closed neighborhoods. But how should I show the disjointness of such neighborhoods?

try intersecting with complements

Every subset of any topological space $X$ has a closed neighbourhood: $X$ itself.

@TheoBendit This is not necessarily correct, in my definition the neighborhood of $A$ need to contains an open subset which contains $A$.

@GaoMinghao Is $X$ not an open set containing $A$, that is also contained in $X$?

@TheoBendit Yes this makes sense, I think my professor made a mistake here, and I guess it should be "closed neighbourhoods form a neighborhood basis". Thank you anyway

Let $X$ be a topological space. $X$ is normal if each pair of disjoint closed sets can be separated by disjoint open neighborhoods (let $C, D$ be closed sets in $X$ such that $C \cap D = \emptyset$, there exist $A, B$ open sets in $X$ such that $C \subseteq A$, $D \subseteq B$, $A \cap B = \emptyset$).
$X$ is normal if, and only if, given $C, A \subseteq X$ such that $C$ is closed in $X$, $A$ is open in $X$, and $C \subseteq A$, then there exist an open set $U$ and a closed set $V$ such that $C \subseteq U \subseteq V \subseteq A$.
Indeed, as you have said in the comments, $X$ is normal if, and only if, each closed set has a neighborhood basis whose elements are closed sets. Each closed set having a closed neighborhood isn't enough. As others have commented, in every space, $X$ is a clopen neighborhood of each of its subsets. Yet, there are non-normal spaces, like the particular point topology on a set with $3$ or more elements.
Proof:
Let $C$ be closed in $X$ and let $A$ be open in $X$ such that $C \subseteq A$. Then, $C \cap (X\setminus A) = \emptyset$. As $X$ is normal (by hypothesis), then there exist $U$, $V$ disjoint open sets such that $C \subseteq U$ and $(X\setminus A) \subseteq V$. Therefore, $C \subseteq U \subseteq (X\setminus V) \subseteq A$.
Let $C, D$ be closed sets in $X$ such that $C \cap D = \emptyset$. Then, $C \subseteq (X\setminus D)$. By hypothesis, there exist $U$ open set in $X$ and $V$ closed set in $X$ such that $C \subseteq U \subseteq V \subseteq (X\setminus D)$. Therefore, $C \subseteq U$, $D \subseteq (X\setminus V)$ and $U \cap (X\setminus V) = \emptyset$.
